# how to remove one item from firebase example, I want to remove just "childid1" from children

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

[image]
I want to remove the string "childid1" from the list containing "chilidid1,childid2,childid3,..."
From firebase realtime

I want to remove the string "childid1" from the list containing "chilidid1,childid2,childid3,..."
From firebase realtime

Comment: Can you share what you have done so far

Answer (score 2):

I guess that database you made is for learning how a real time database works on firebase.

Your database strtucture is wrong. You should redo-it and make it like this:

```
-classid1
     -children:
          -child1: ""
          -child2: ""
```

You cannot have multiple values in a child key unless it is a list.
In that case, you need to create a DatabaseReference that gets the value and classifies it to a list, then you do whatever you want with that list and then post it back to the database.
Example:

```
         DatabaseReference childsRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("classes").child("classid1");
    
    childsRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
     @Override
                public void onDataChange(@NonNull @NotNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
                    ArrayList[] childrenList = 
                    snapshot.child("children").getValue(List.class);
                    childrenList[0] = "changedchild1"
                    snapshot.child("children").setValue(childrenList[0]);
                }
    
                @Override
                public void onCancelled(@NonNull @NotNull DatabaseError error) {
    
                }
    }
```

If you want to remove the child programmatically, simply change this on the code I placed before, inside onDataChange method:

```
public void onDataChange(@NonNull @NotNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {  
                    snapshot.child("children").removeValue();
                }
```

Answer (score 1):

The property called `children` in your database is actually a single string value. To remove the `child1` substring from it, you'll have to:

1. Read the entire `children` property into your application code.
2. Modify the string to remove the (first) `child1`.
3. Write the modified string back to the database.

Alternatively you can do what OneKe [answered](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71707727/209103) and turn the `children` property into a list (using `push()` to generate the keys) or into a map (where `child1` and all are keys and they all have a value of `true`).

Answer (score 0):

I find a solution thnks , "Frank van Puffelen" for  the  idea i code it
that's is the code

```
 delBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
           //child.removeValue();
           final String currentClass;
         //   Toast.makeText(getContext(), ChildCode, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            DatabaseReference db = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("classes");
            currentClass = ClassFragment.classid;
            final DatabaseReference db2 = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("classes").child(currentClass);

          final String value= db.child("classes").child(currentClass).child("children").toString();

            db2.child("children").addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                    String ids_str = dataSnapshot.getValue().toString();

                    String str1 = ids_str;
                    String str2=childid+",";
                    //String replace = ids_str.replace("str1", "");
                  // String ret= ids_str.replace(str1,"");
                   // Toast.makeText(getContext(), ret, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                    String returnedString = ids_str.replace( str2, "" );
                  //  Toast.makeText(getContext(), returnedString, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    //Toast.makeText(getContext(), returnedString, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    db2.child("children").setValue(returnedString);
                    Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Successfully updated user", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                }
```